# Multiple Transmitter Localization - Channel Modelling

Tags: channel, localization

I read in this paper about to localize multiple transmitter in a wireless scenario. I know from other source that this hypothesis is completely false. What do you think? Is there in the literature something that is confirmed about this?

[image]

Comment: "I know from other source that this hypothesis is completely false", what hypothesis? This is a introduction to some system model, but what is your question?

Comment: Is the RSS the sum of the several contributions?

Comment: Sure why not? There are multiple transmitters after all